# Quick Integration by Parts Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

So, came across the following question while I was studying for a test:

"Let $g$ be a differentiable function such that $\int g(x)e^{\frac{x}{4}}dx=4g(x)e^{\frac{x}{4}}-\int 8x^2e^{\frac{x}{4}}dx$ What's a possible expression for $g(x)$?"

We're talking about integration by parts, and I assumed that I should apply that formula ($\int udv = uv-\int vdu$) here, but it seems like after using that that there's no formula given for $g(x)$? I'm a bit lost and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $ \frac{2}{3} x^3 $?

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused on how you got there though.

Comment: I would differentiate both sides and compare.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still a little confused, if I take the derivative of an integral that cancels it out right? So it'd basically be the same thing as just taking the integral signs away and going from there?

Comment: IBP is: $ \int u v’ dx = u v - \int u’ v dx $. Here, my v’ is $e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and then I figured out that $u$ is $g(x)$ and must equal $\frac{2}{3} x^3$.

Comment: The formula in the question is compact but probably not as helpful for this question as my version of the formula.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to see where you're coming from. So could you essentially just take the integral of $u'$ and get $u$ from that?

Comment: I'm just not seeing how you got $u$ from that formula.

Comment: Yes, the integral of u’ is u because integration is the reverse of differentiation. See calculus’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

I write down the two terms so that you can compare them.

$$\int g(x)\cdot e^{\frac{x}{4}}\, dx=g(x)\cdot 4e^{\frac{x}{4}}-\int 8x^2e^{\frac{x}{4}}\, dx$$

$\begin{array}{}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \Huge\Updownarrow  \large ➀ &  \qquad \Huge\Updownarrow \large ➁ &   \quad   \ \Huge\Updownarrow \large ➂ \end{array}$

$$\int g(x)^{}\cdot h^{'}(x)\, dx=g(x)\cdot h^{}(x)-\int g(x)^{'}\cdot h^{}(x)\, dx$$

$\large ➀$ Identify $h^{'}(x)$

$\large ➁$ Check if $h^{}(x)=4e^{\frac{x}4}$

$\large ➂$ Extract $h(x)$ so that the remaining part is $g^{'}(x)$. Then integrate to obtain $g^{}(x)$.